# saving image with wrong fileType while upload it from remote server

Tags: php, image, types

I've found an interesting thing, when I save picture like this (on input i have *.txt file with only one URL of image)

```
<?

function cu($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://treto.ru');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $res_curl = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $res_curl;
}

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
foreach($_FILES as $file)
{
    $orig = $uploaddir .trim(basename($file['name']));
    if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $orig))
    {
        $images_arr = file($orig);

        foreach($images_arr as $v)
        {
            $data = cu(trim($v));  // get pic through cURL (it's the only way in my case)
            $filename = basename($v);
            $arr67 = explode('.',$filename);
            $ext = $arr67[count($arr67)-1];
            $save = rand(1000,9999).'__'.time().'.jpg';

            if(!is_file($uploaddir.$save))
            {                                       
                $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
                if ($im !== false)
                {                               
                    imagepng($im,$uploaddir.$save);
                    imagedestroy($im);
                    $sizes = getimagesize($uploaddir.$save);
                    echo '<img src="'.$uploaddir.$save.'" alt="rt" title="'.$sizes[0].'*'.$sizes[1].'.'.$ext.'" border="0"><br />';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'An error occurred.<br />';
                }      
            }
            else
            {
                $sizes = getimagesize($uploaddir.$filename);
                echo '<img src="'.$uploaddir.$filename.'" alt="hh" title="'.$sizes[0].'*'.$sizes[1].'" border="0"><br />';
            }               
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'error';
    }            
}

?>
```

I receive right coded and saved image, outputed to the browser...

but when I replace  '.jpg'  with  '.'.$ext   ...

(here is the full code)

```
<?

function cu($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://treto.ru');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $res_curl = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $res_curl;
}

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
foreach($_FILES as $file)
{
    $orig = $uploaddir .trim(basename($file['name']));
    if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $orig))
    {
        $images_arr = file($orig);

        foreach($images_arr as $v)
        {
            $data = cu(trim($v));  // get pic through cURL (it's the only way in my case)
            $filename = basename($v);
            $arr67 = explode('.',$filename);
            $ext = $arr67[count($arr67)-1];
            $save = rand(1000,9999).'__'.time().'.'.$ext;

            if(!is_file($uploaddir.$save))
            {                                       
                $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
                if ($im !== false)
                {                               
                    imagepng($im,$uploaddir.$save);
                    imagedestroy($im);
                    $sizes = getimagesize($uploaddir.$save);
                    echo '<img src="'.$uploaddir.$save.'" alt="rt" title="'.$sizes[0].'*'.$sizes[1].'.'.$ext.'" border="0"><br />';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'An error occurred.<br />';
                }      
            }
            else
            {
                $sizes = getimagesize($uploaddir.$filename);
                echo '<img src="'.$uploaddir.$filename.'" alt="hh" title="'.$sizes[0].'*'.$sizes[1].'" border="0"><br />';
            }               
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'error';
    }            
}

?>
```

saved file has another type - text/x-generic (but I need image/x-generic), [like this](http://wovo4ka.ru/my/screen072.png) (in the middle)

I checked - files have the same content,

**so what is it - error in server configuration or php-bug?**

P.S. tested on these files

wovo4ka.ru/pic/wovo4ka_logo.jpg

treto.ru/img_lb/Settecento/.IT/per_sito/ambienti/01.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Check the extension. It will result in text/x-generic if for example the file was wovo4ka.ru/pic/wovo4ka_logo.JPG instead of a lowercase jpg

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i checked the extension and it is in lowercase, so your assumption is not suitable here...